# Why I failed to query database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Currently, I'm using the 000webhost to build my website. I also configure Wordpress in the 000Webhost free hosting. Currently, my problem is when I try to login, it shows me the message

```
 Failed to query database Access denied for user 'id1351040_wp_f95ca011d778539df40db16f9d312e34'@'%' to database 'login_table'
```

Based on my Wordpress pages, I created the form and the coding will be shown below

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../wp-content/themes/main/process.php" onsubmit="return check();">
```

According to the Phpmyadmin, this is the directory
 /public_html/wp-content/themes/main/process.php which let the form action to link it to here. The code for process.php will be shown as below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);

// connect to the server and select database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1351040_wp_f95ca011d778539df40db16f9d312e34", "xxxxxx", "id1351040_wp_f95ca011d778539df40db16f9d312e34");
mysqli_select_db($con,"login_table") or die(mysqli_error($con));

// Get values passe from form in login.php file
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

// to prevent mysql injection
$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

// Query the database for user
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from login where ID = '$username' and Password = '$password'")
            or die("Failed to query database ".mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result);

session_start();
if($row['ID'] == $username && $row['Password'] == $password ){
    header( 'Location: https://xxxxxx/' ) ; 
    }
else{
    echo "Failed to login!";
}

?>
```

The screenshot for phpmyadmin
[Screenshot of Phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCJu.jpg)
This is the result of
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvbIt.jpg)

Comment: This looks like a problem with your `mysqli_connect` parameters or database permissions. It is telling you your password or user is incorrect, or that your user doesn't have permissions to view that particular database. I would double check your username and password and check your permission levels for 'login_table'

Comment: Sidenote: `mysqli_fetch_array()` does not use a connection parameter, nor more than 1 argument neither.

Comment: btw; that code is totally unsafe to be used in a live environment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- why would you say that(unsafe)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You know WP has a db class you can use right out of the box, right? complete with prepared statements (which may be what fred was referring to) and all that. You look like you're deliberately trying to circumvent the WP system for reasons unknown. Might be easier to use the tools at your disposal than to reinvent a wheel that's already being loaded

Comment: @MichellaeKang plain text passwords

Comment: @KaiQing Currently, I'm now building login website by using 000webhost. I try to login with username and password but it said that the query database has failed. Basically, when I login, if it is successful, it will jump to another pages and vice-versa. All the data have been inserted in the database already. Now I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database.